# How to know what drivers and video card am I using?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, kde, plasma

I am running KDE Neon, there isnt an app called software and updates like there is in ubuntu. How do I know that im running not the open source driver and actually using my gpu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the `glxinfo` command in the terminal:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

Here's a good article - [How to get information about graphics card (GPU) on Linux](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-get-gpu-information/)

Answer (score 4):

glxinfo wasn't on the usb boot disk.  I read the article above and voila!
I ran this from the USB boot cd of 16.04 and it came right up:

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to check is go to Settings -> Details -> About

[image: Settings]

Comment: What does that do if there are two different GPUs?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex it will only show the GPU which is currently using